# Web application with one schema per User

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant

I am trying to enable my web application to use one (*MySQL*) schema per user.
I am using *Spring* with *JPA* along with *Hibernate*.
Is the Hibernate Multi-tenancy concept relevant?
The way I am trying to do it is

- (a) have a `EntityManagerFactory` per `HTTPSession` and
- (b) set the    schema in it at login.

I have figured out how to do (b), but I still have issues doing (a).
I tried putting `@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)`, but what about the global `EntityManagerFactory`?

Any help?

Comment: You don't want a `EntityManagerFactory` per session. It takes way too much time to create one and it just doesn't make sense and makes things really complicated. You basically have a multi tenant situation and you should configure that appropriately. With multi tenancy setup you just have a single `EntityManagerFactory` as you should.

Comment: Could you give details of how to configure it approprietely? Keep in mind that I need one connection pool but different schema per user (HttpSession).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own ConnectionProvider and there make extra settings.
But I think that you have large problems with the architecture your application if you want to do one schema per user.

**UPD1**

If you use spring. You can try to declare a bean with own impl of ConnectionProvider in Session scope.

But there is a big problem. Hibernate make the ConnectionProvider. It means that you have to impl own ServiceRegistry (with working through Spring) and override StandardServiceRegistryBuilder, and impl EntityManagerFactoryBuilder (based on EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl but with your StandardServiceRegistryBuilder).

When new session have been created it'll use ConnectionProvider to create the connection (Probably you'll have to override some classes).

Comment: This does not answer the question: How do I define which settings to be used per HttpSession?

Answer (score 0):

This is really not suggested.. This will harm you later, you can't do differnt schema for diffrent user. You can always create you own properties to the connection..

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.configure();
System.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password",pass);
System.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username",usr);
System.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", driver_class);
System.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", driver_url);
System.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
// etc, etc, for all properties
cfg.setProperties(System.getProperties());
sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
```

It can be something like that.. But this is WRONG!